# ¿como soluciono error al mostrar datos de mysql?

Tags: php, mysqli

hola que tal estoy haciendo una pagina de usuario
en esta se debe de mostrar los datos ingresados por el usuario 
este es el codigo

```
<body>
<?php

 session_start();
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","datos_usuario");     
 $nombre_user= $_POST['nombre'];
 $apellido_user= $_POST['apellido'];
 $clave_user= $_POST['clave'];
 $telefono_user= $_POST['telefono'];
 $edad_user= $_POST['edad'];
 $email_user= $_POST['email'];

 $resultado =  mysqli_query($link,"SELECT nombre,apellido,clave,telefono,edad,email FROM datos WHERE nombre='$nombre_user'
    AND apellido='$apellido_user' AND telefono ='$telefono_user' AND clave ='$clave_user' AND edad='$edad_user' AND email='$email_user'");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($link,$resultado) ;
?>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

 <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="http://lacodeid.com">Mi informacion<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">menu usuario</h3>
      </div>
    <h1><br>Bienvenido al menu de usuario</br></h1>
      <?php
      echo utf8_decode($row['nombre,apellido,clave,telefono,edad,email']);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

he omitido todo lo que conlleva css 
el problema esta en que me aparece error en todas las variables de la base de datos tales como 'nombre' 'telefono' etc... y no se el porque
mi proyecto consta de un registro de un login y de un panel de usuario el registro y el login ya estan completamente listo y funcionando
cabe aclarar que la base de datos se llama datos_usuario y que su tabla es datos

exactamente este es el error que me aparece
(Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 174

Notice: Undefined index: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 175

Notice: Undefined index: clave in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 176

Notice: Undefined index: telefono in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 177

Notice: Undefined index: edad in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 178

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 179

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 183)

los datos vienen de el registro este es el codigo del registro

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
 $db = mysqli_select_db($link,"datos_usuario") or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");

 if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
     $clave =$_POST['clave'];
     $rclave =$_POST['rclave'];
     $telefono =$_POST['telefono'];
     $edad =$_POST['edad'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];

 }

 if ($clave != $rclave) {
        die('Las contraseñas no coinciden, Verifique <br /> <a href="index.html">Volver</a>');
    }
 $nuevo_email=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM datos WHERE email='$email'"); 
 $verificar=mysqli_num_rows($nuevo_email);
  if($verificar>0) 
    { 
         echo " 
         <p class='avisos'>La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada</p> 
         <p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p> 
         "; 
     } else {
         mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$apellido','$clave','$telefono','$edad','$email')");



    echo " <center>felicidades ya estas registrado</center>
        <center><td><label><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Iniciar sesion\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right\"></input></label></td></center>";


    }
?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el error exacto que te sale

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores. Me parece que en otra pregunta te sugerí que sometas a prueba tus variables, verificando si existen en el POST. Los mensajes de error parecen indicar que el POST no viene con los datos que estás buscando:

> `Notice: Undefined index: nombre in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\usuario.php on line 174`

...etc

Luego, no le estás pasando la conexión a la llamada de `mysqli_query`. Aunque la función usa por defecto la conexión actual, conviene pasarle el parámetro, por claridad en el código.

Por otra parte, le estás pasando un parámetro de más a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, eso es lo que significa el mensaje:

> `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Esa función no necesita la conexión como parámetro, solamente el resultado de la consulta.

Deberías evitar el constante uso de `utf8_decode` sobre los datos, estableciendo un charset a la conexión y al documento (esto te lo sugerí también en otra respuesta).

La forma de leer los datos tampoco es correcta:

```
$row['nombre,apellido,clave,telefono,edad,email']
```

`$row` será un array con sus claves por separado, para acceder tienes que usar cada clave diferenciada: `$row['nombre`]`,`$row['apellido']`, etc.

Debes revisar también tu forma de usar HTML. Organiza bien el documento, poniendo primero los encabezados, título, codificación, etc. Otro error que cometes es cerrar mal ciertas etiquetas, por ejemplo el `br` no se cierra así: `</br>`, sino así: `<br />` en HTML estricto. Todo eso, aunque sea imperceptible, produce un HTML erróneo que no validaría.

Vamos a tratar de corregir el código. Faltan más controles (como ya te dije en otra pregunta), pero no los pondré, para no liarte demasiado. Pero tenlo en cuenta si te quieres ahorrar horas depurando el código y crear un código controlado en todos los sentidos y seguro implementando consultas preparadas.

Aquí he tratado de aplicar todo lo dicho en la respuesta. Si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Título de la página</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container">
    <?php
        $nombre_user= !empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
        $apellido_user= !empty($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : NULL;
        $clave_user= !empty($_POST['clave']) ? $_POST['clave'] : NULL;
        $telefono_user= !empty($_POST['telefono']) ? $_POST['telefono'] : NULL;
        $edad_user= !empty($_POST['edad']) ? $_POST['edad'] : NULL;
        $email_user= !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;

        if ($nombre_user && $apellido_user && $clave_user && $telefono_user && $edad_user && $email_user) {
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","datos_usuario");
            #Haz esto para evitar el constanto uso de utf8_decode sobre los datos
            mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");     
            $sql="SELECT nombre,apellido,clave,telefono,edad,email FROM datos WHERE nombre='$nombre_user'
            AND apellido='$apellido_user' AND telefono ='$telefono_user' AND clave ='$clave_user' AND edad='$edad_user' AND email='$email_user'";
            $resultado =  mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ;
    ?>

            <div class="header clearfix">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" href="http://lacodeid.com">Mi informacion<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h3 class="text-muted">menu usuario</h3>
            </div>
            <h1><br>Bienvenido al menu de usuario<br /></h1>
    <?php
            echo "$row[nombre]\n,$row[apellido]\n,$row[clave]\n,$row[telefono]\n,$row[edad]\n,$row[email]\n)";
        } else {
            echo "Falta alguno de los datos enviados, revise el formulario";
        }
    ?>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100702/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-soluciono-error-al-mostrar-datos-de-mysq).